# picking an item from an array, and making that item the first one in the list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array and an empty drop down list. I need to populate my drop down list with my array. However, choosing an item should make it the first item in the list, and the list should continue alphabetically from there. This is what I have, but the drop down list should not be in alphabetical order at first. It should only get in alphabetical order once someone chooses an item.

Javascript:

```
var array = ["vintage", "frames", "treats", "engraved", "stickers", "jewelerybox", "flask"];



    array.sort(function(val1, val2) {
      return val1.localeCompare(val2);
    });

    var select = document.getElementById("dropdownList");

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

      select.innerHTML += '<option>' + array[i] + '</option>';

    }
```

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdownList">

</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select.onchange = function() {
    var selectedText = select.selectedOptions[0].textContent;//get text of selected item
    select.innerHTML = '';//remove everything form select
    array.sort(function(val1, val2) {//sort array
        if (val1 === selectedText) {//val1 should be on first if its equal to selectedText
            return -1
        } else if (val2 === selectedText) {//val1 should be on first if its equal to selectedText
            return 1;
        } else {
            return val1.localeCompare(val2);
        }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {//add everything back
        select.innerHTML += '<option>' + array[i] + '</option>';//consider using document.createElement
    }  
}
```